# How to implement ALLO command on Apache FTP?

Tags: apache, ftp

We have an embedded Apache FTP server running in a gateway for several years. It always worked without problems.

But now a customer is trying to connect with a device of a brand that we've never had before, and contrary to all other clients so far, that thing sends the ALLO command in advance to make sure the server has enough space.

But Apache FTP doesn't seem to know that command. the trace log states:

> RECEIVED: ALLO 77482
>   SENT: 502 Command ALLO not implemented.

following which the client cuts the connection.

The command is also not present in the Apache documentation:
https://mina.apache.org/ftpserver-project/ftpserver_commands.html

So the question is, can I plug my own implementation into the server somehow?
Just to be clear, I'm not asking how to implement the functionality. Just how I can pass my own implementation to Apache FTP for use. If that is possible without touching the source code.

Since the application in question has been running very stable for a long time, I would really hate to tear the Apache FTP server out of there and embed another one...

Comment: So are you asking how to *configure* a proprietary FTP server based on Apache Mina to somehow handle a new FTP command?

Comment: Apache FTP is not based on Mina as far as I know, I think it's older. I guess configuring would be the appropriate term, though. In any case, I got it figured out, much to my surprise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, that was surprisingly simple once I dug myself through to the right code.

The implementation of a command is simple enough, in this case I've just started with a stub for testing:

```
class ALLO : AbstractCommand() {

    override fun execute(session: FtpIoSession, context: FtpServerContext, request: FtpRequest) {

        session.write(LocalizedFtpReply.translate(session, request, context,
                FtpReply.REPLY_200_COMMAND_OKAY, "ALLO", "bring it!"))
    }
}
```

Inherit AbstractCommand, override execute and write a response to the session.

The question is of course then how to make the server aware of the implementation, which also turns out to be really simple, although there sure as hell doesn't seem to be any documentation around. But you can just instantiate a CommandFactoryFactory, map your implementation, build the CommandFactory and set it in the FtpServerFactory:

```
        val commandFactoryFactory = CommandFactoryFactory()
        commandFactoryFactory.addCommand("ALLO", ALLO())
        serverFactory.commandFactory = commandFactoryFactory.createCommandFactory()
```